how to set Superscript/subscript/strike on specific text in cell in word using office js
Based on my object I have inserting text in word table cell and applying content control
After that in Some cell I want to set Superscript/subscript/strike on some specific characters in cell(not whole text).
Example 21st Jan 2022 in that I inserted whole text in cell but I want to set 'st' as superscript using office-js.
This Superscript/subscript/strike occurrence can be multiple in one cell.
I have start-Index and End-Index for Superscript/subscript/strike character in my object.
Here is my code snippet
After inserting text I want to give style Superscript/subscript/strike
async function UpdateValueInTableNew(selectedTbl, currentTblObject) {
    try {
        await Word.run(async function (context) {
            console.time("UpdateValueInTableNew");
            const docCC = context.document.contentControls;
            docCC.load("items");
            await context.sync();
            var findTbl = docCC.items.filter(a => a.tag == selectedTbl);//Content controlID of my table
            var table = findTbl[0].parentTable;
            context.load(table, 'rows/items/rowIndex,rowCount,rows/items/cells/items/body/font/superscript,rows/items/cells/items/body/contentControls/items/tag,rows/items/cells/items/body/contentControls/items/text,rows/items/cells/items/value,rows/items/cells/items/cellIndex,rows/items/cells/items/value,rows/items/cells/items/body/font');
            var ctrlTime
            await context.sync();
            var rows = table.rows;
            console.log(table);
            for (let ii = 0; ii < rows.items.length; ii++) {
                let row = rows.items[ii];
                for (let jj = 0; jj < (row.cells.items.length); jj++) {
                    let cell = row.cells.items[jj];
                    let cc = cell.body.contentControls.items;
                    let cellIndex = cell.cellIndex;
                    let rowIndex = row.rowIndex;
                    let data = null;
                    data = currentTblObject[ii][jj];
                    let ctrlList = cell.body.contentControls;
                    var ctrl;
                    for (let x = 0; x < ctrlList.length; x++) {
                        if (ctrlList[x].tag == data.Fact) {
                            ctrl = ctrlList[x];
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    let cellBody = cell.body;
                    if (data) {
                            if (data.CellDisplayValue != "")
                            {
                                cellBody.insertText(data.CellDisplayValue.trim(), "Replace");
                                ctrl = cellBody.insertContentControl();
                                ctrl.tag = data.Fact;
                            }
                            else {
                                cellBody.clear();
                            }
                            
                        }
                    }                   
                }
            }
            await context.sync();
            return true;
        });
    }
    catch (ex) {       
       
        return false;

    }
}

here is my data object which look like this
string CellDisplayValue;
string Fact; //Content control ID
 List<Tuple<string,int,int>> Effects

in tuple first string type has "Sup","Sub","Strike" other 2 has start-Index and end Index
